# C# - finding the common elements in a list of list of integers

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of list of items like in the following.

```
List<List<int>> testItems=new List<List<int>>();
```

I have added items to it like this.

```
List<int> item=new List<item>();
item.clear();

item.Add(3);
item.Add(5);
item.Add(7);

testItems.Add(item);

item.clear();
item.Add(10);
item.Add(3);

testItems.Add(item);

item.clear();
item.Add(1);
item.Add(8);
item.Add(3);
item.Add(9);

testItems.Add(item);
```

Now what I want to do is I want to extract the elements common to all the lists and add it to another list called finalList.

```
List<int> finalList = new List<int>();
```

I have tried the following.

```
int count;
foreach (List<int> a in testItems)
{
    count = 0;
    foreach (int b in a)
    {
        foreach (List<int> c in testItems)
        {
            foreach (int d in c)
            {
                if (d == b)
                {
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (count == a.Count)
            finalList.Add(b);
    }
}
```

I know this solution is not optimal and does not provide what I need. It can possibly add the same item several times. Can someone help me to fix it ?

Comment: What I mean by "all the lists" is the set of lists contained in testItems. It is a list of list of integers. It's a lengthy code. The list created ( finalList) is gonna be used in some other part of the code

Comment: Are you bound to using lists? Using [HashSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) seems more appropriate (and efficient) for your case here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code for adding items is not adding three different items. As you are reusing the item, the code is equivalent to:

```
  List<int> item=new List<int>();
  item.Add(1);
  item.Add(8);
  item.Add(3);
  item.Add(9);

  testItems.Add(item);
  testItems.Add(item);
  testItems.Add(item);
```

You need to create new items instead of reusing the same item:

```
  List<int> item = new List<int>();
  item.Add(3);
  item.Add(5);
  item.Add(7);
  testItems.Add(item);

  item = new List<int>();
  item.Add(10);
  item.Add(3);
  testItems.Add(item);

  item = new List<int>();
  item.Add(1);
  item.Add(8);
  item.Add(3);
  item.Add(9);
  testItems.Add(item);
```

For a more efficient way to get the numbers common to all items, you can loop through all values in the first item, and check which exists in all the other items:

```
List<int> finalList =
  testItems[0].Where(
    i => testItems.Skip(1).All(x => x.Contains(i))
  ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ method [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb355408(v=vs.110).aspx)

You will get something like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> result = testItems[0];
for(int i = 1; i < testItems.Count; i++)
{
    result = result.Intersect(testItems[i]);
}
```

You get your intersection in the result variable.

But are you really sure that you need this strange looking list of lists?